# Moodle: How to Assign One Teacher for One Course only

Tags: admin, moodle, user-roles

I want to assign one teacher for one course only - specific teacher for specific course and that course enrolled students to manage.

How can I do from Admin Panel?

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a teacher to a course has to be done in the course page. There, use the `Administration block`, and click `Course administration > Users > Enrolled users`.

This is where you can assign a teacher by adding a user with the role "teacher" using the `Enrol user` button.